# Cassandra launch GC and high response time at almost zero load

Tags: cassandra

I have cassandra db 3.11.

Using following table

```
create table if not exists events(
id TimeUUID,
added_at timestamp,
event text,
PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Now i have delay upto 1 second and 100% cpu usage on query like

```
select * from events
```

Even when i have HEAP at 8Gb and 1 record in table(event is 100bytes long).

Sure when do request using key i got less then 1ms response time, but at least sometimes i need do full scan.

But still question: what i am missing and why it running so long to do full table check?

Answer (score 0):

Seams like it realated to UUID key full scan.

So can be fixed by doing key by (server_id,id).

Comment: Yes, full table scans in Cassandra are a really bad idea.

Comment: Any ideas which db i should use for insert buffer(in memory concurrent inserts and batch select for delete after that).